# Execute a function after rendering of Graph completes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I want to execute a function after the successful rendering of a Graph. SuccessfulRendering() is running before the display completes. Any Idea how can we do this? I want to take the screenshot of the screen in SuccessfulRendering() function after the display completes, that's why I've to wait for the graph to be rendered completely.

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

class LineChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // To avoid unnecessary update keep all options in the state.
      chartOptions: {
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        },
        series: [
          { data: [1, 2, 3] }
        ]
      },
      hoverData: null
    };
  }


  SuccessfulRendering=()=>{
    console.log('Successfully rendered!!')
  }

  updateSeries = () => {
    // The chart is updated only with new options.
    this.setState({ 
      chartOptions: {
        series: [
          { data: [Math.random() * 5, 2, 1]}
        ]
      }
    },()=>{
      this.SuccessfulRendering()
    });

  }

  render() {
    const { chartOptions, hoverData } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={chartOptions}
        />
      <h3>Hovering over {hoverData}</h3>
      <button onClick={this.updateSeries.bind(this)}>Update Series</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<LineChart />, document.getElementById('root'),()=>{
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a problem which you are struggling to is related to the animation. In this case, you should disable it or delay the calling of the SuccessfulRendering function by using **setTimeout**.

Demo without animation after the chart update: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-2volr

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `callback`? Check it [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react)

Comment: Yes. But it is still running function before complete of rendering.

Comment: I found this example in the official Highchart docs that might be of help: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-load/